# Check empty string in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts

How to check for Empty String/Null String in Struts-JSP page.

Struts Tag -  does not works?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See below:

```
<c:if test='${not empty param.whatever}'>
   ...
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<logic:empty param="<%= yourString %>">
```

or if the string you want to check is a property of a bean :

```
<logic:empty name="yourBean" property="yourBeanStringProperty">
```

Answer (score -5):

```
String foo = null;
if(foo == null or foo.length() ==0) // The string is null
```